# How do I print the sum of first and last elements, followed by the sum of the second and second-to-last, and so on?

Tags: c++, c++11

Im very new to programming, and am working through the C++ Primer 5th edition. One of the exercises requires me to enter a set of integers into a vector and print the  sum of the first and last elements, followed by the second and second-to-last etc.

I have tried a number of approaches which I found on GitHub and other answers to iteration-through-vector related questions... but none have worked. 
Here is my most recent attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> Vect;
    int Num;

    while (std::cin >> Num) {
        Vect.push_back(Num);

        for (decltype(Vect.size()) A = 0, B = Vect.size() -1 ; A != B; ++A, --B) {
            std::cout << Vect[A] + Vect[B] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You can't do the sum until *after* the user is finished with the input.

Comment: You also need to be sure your termination condition works for both even- and odd-sized input.

Comment: Got a quick question. And really don't want to infuriate anyone. Why would one not use the suggestion that I made below that takes all safety measures one could wish for and instead want to deal with indexes? Again, please consider not down voting, I would just like to understand. The only place my code could break is if the `back_inserter` cannot allocate more memory. But that one could ensure beforehand by preallocation of `res` and as far as I know there is strong exception safety during calculation. The code even works with unallocated vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should understand why is your code crashing?**

your asking the compiler to enter elements and do some logic at the same time, in your case you enter the number then check the vector size then do the logic which is print the sum of the first and last then A++ and B-- to get the second first and second last.

let's debug to understand more

assume you compiled and you entered the first input is 5 which means now you have one element `{5}`
after inserting the number the compiler will go to next line to continue the logic then will find the condition `A != B` and you have one element `{5}` which means A=B  so, the compiler will not enter the loop to run the logic

then the second input is 5 which means now you have tow elements `{5,5}`
after inserting the number the compiler will go to next line to continue the logic then will find the condition `A != B` and you have one element `{5,5}` which means A!=B  so, the compiler will enter the loop to run the logic.

the compiler will sum the first and last (A=vect[0] and B= vect[1] the only 2 elements in the vector) elements in the vector 5+5 and will print the result 10 then will  A++ and B--, A will be A=vec[1] and B will be B=vect [0] and also the result will be 10 then will  A++ and B--  **>>** here is the issue the compiler will not find any element with vect[-1] or vect[2] so, the application will crash.

**Learning lessons**

separate your input from your code logic if you will not need to do any logic during the input.

you should put your for loop outside the while loop.

**Update:**  your code should be like

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    
    vector<int> Vect;
    int Num;

    while (cin >> Num) {
        Vect.push_back(Num);
       
    }

     for (decltype(Vect.size()) A = 0, B = Vect.size() -1 ; A < B; ++A, --B) {
            cout << Vect[A] + Vect[B] << std::endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

you can see I also change the condition  `A != B` to `A < B` because your condition will let `A` increase forever and `B` will decrease forever and will lead your app to carsh

also, do not forget to limit your input to do not enter to infinity loop of input
please see the below code after limiting the input " I put 4 number as example"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    
    vector<int> Vect;
    int Num,c=0;

    while (c<4) {
        cin >> Num;
        Vect.push_back(Num);
       c++;
    }

     for (decltype(Vect.size()) A = 0, B = Vect.size() -1 ; A < B; ++A, --B) {
            cout << Vect[A] + Vect[B] << std::endl;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your detailed response, really helped me understand where I was going wrong. Now I can finally continue through the book haha :)

Answer (score 6):

You're on the right track, just make sure to read the input before doing any processing on it. 
Basically, the part to sum the elements should be outside the while loop to read input.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
std::vector<int> a(100), res;
std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);
std::transform(
  a.begin(), a.begin()+a.size()/2, a.rbegin(), 
  std::back_inserter(res), std::plus<int>());
```

Comment: <<Im very new to programming>> This may be "safe", but is it a useful first step learning example? I would certainly agree that using vectors and iterators would be better, but I have problems reading what/how this.

Comment: I'd definitely say that if you are learning C++ in 2018 you really should learn the C++ of 2018 and not that of 1990. Every sane person that you are going to apply with as a C++ developer will ask you about c++14/c++17. It is a matter of safety and maintainability before about anything else. You cannot break the above code, if you add `res.reserve(a.size()/2)` it is impossible to break the above code with anything.

Answer (score 0):

c++ array approach assuming `a[N]` array:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0, j = N - 1; i <= j; ++i, --j){
   cout<<a[i] + a[j]<<endl;
}
```